# Can't get PyCharm to recognize Anaconda imports

Tags: python, python3, pycharm, anaconda

I've done this on my Windows computer and it works fine, so I'm pretty sure it's possible and I'm just doing something wrong on my part.

I went ahead and installed anaconda for python 3 as well as installed PyCharm.

On PyCharm, i set the interpreter to use Anaconda and I see a list of all the packages installed.

Now I'm trying to run a script and the error I get is

```
File "/home/dgameman1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'
```

Not sure how I can fix this issue. Any ideas?

Thanks again!

Comment: Omg. I figured it out.
When I created the project, I picked a different interpreter

Comment: Now you know the answer, you can write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. When I created the project, I picked a different interpreter than the one I wanted to use after going into the settings of PyCharm.

I just redid the project.